# Java wrapper for Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, java

I am interested in building an Android or [Java ME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Micro_Edition) application. Is there a Java wrapper?

Comment: Who-hoo! When you get something far enough along and need beta testers, count me in!

Comment: @CommonsWare: I've actually decided to leave it a while and see if anyone else builds a decent app. That way I only have to build one if no-one else does =P

Answer (score 5):

[**StackWrap4J**](https://stackapps.com/questions/818/stackwrap4j-java-wrapper) has been released fairly recently.  It is completely up to date with the latest version of the API. (As of June 24th, V0.9)  It has been tested and works on the Android platform.

We are still developing it and will continue to support it as the API changes.

If you are interested in switching to it, we will work with you to make the transition easy.

Comment: Do you have links to tutorials and examples for using StackWrap4J?

Comment: @PatrickW.McMahon All of the documentation is in the linked post. However, I'm not sure if the library will work any more. It was built against a quite old version of the API.

Answer (score 3):

I started working on one over the weekend. I went ahead and stuck it on github if you want to look. I'm shooting for a version that will have most functionality stometime this week.

http://github.com/carsonmcdonald/Stack-Apps-Java-Library

Comment: have you updated this to `V0.9` yet?

Comment: @jjnguy I plan on it but I started working on other parts of it before v0.9 and I've just been too lazy to stash the changes and update it. There is just one place you have to make the change.

Answer (score 3):

I have released the beta snapshot version of my wrapper here. http://code.google.com/p/stackoverflow-java-sdk/. The announcement is posted on this website as well but I guess it will take some time to show up. :)

Comment: @user, have you updated this to `V0.9` yet?

Comment: @jjnguy yes it's v0.9 compatible. Use the latest from mercurial (not the beta snapshot).

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on one which I'll post about when it's a little more ready to use. I'm focusing on creating immutable, reusable query objects with a nice EDSL-like querying syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following Java Wrapper for stack exchange
https://github.com/sanjivsingh/stackoverflow-java-sdk

- SDK support stack exchange API V2.2.