# StackWrap4J Java wrapper

Tags: library, java, obsolete

The [StackWrap4J 1.0.1](https://sourceforge.net/projects/stackwrap4j/) jar is now available!  *(See the [changelog](https://stackapps.com/questions/818/stackwrap4j-java-wrapper/1225#1225))*

### Sample Code / Screen Shot

The following code snippet was used to test the wrapper in the Android emulator:

```
TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.output);
StackWrapper stackWrap = new StackOverflow();

String displayText = null;

try {
    Stats stats = stackWrap.getStats();
    displayText = "Stack Overflow Statistics";
    displayText += "\nTotal Questions: " + stats.getTotalQuestions();
    displayText += "\nTotal Unanswered: " + stats.getTotalUnanswered();
    displayText += "\nTotal Answers: " + stats.getTotalAnswers();
    displayText += "\nTotal Comments: " + stats.getTotalComments();
    displayText += "\nTotal Votes: " + stats.getTotalVotes();
    displayText += "\nTotal Users: " + stats.getTotalUsers();
}
catch(Exception e){
    displayText = e.getMessage();
}

text.setText(displayText);
```

[image: Android Example]

### About

StackWrap4J is a Java wrapper for the Stack Exchange API.  It is designed to be easy to use, and intuitive to learn while providing the full functionality of the API.

#### License

StackWrap4J is available under the [MIT license](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php).

#### Download

[StackWrap4J](https://sourceforge.net/projects/stackwrap4j/)

#### Platform

StackWrap4J was built using Java 1.5 and tested on Sun's JVM.  It should run on any implementation of the JVM (1.5 or later).  It's also been tested on the Android emulator.  It also runs under the Google App Engine.

### Code

You can download the code from our [SVN repository](http://stackwrap4j.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/stackwrap4j/) hosted on SourceForge.

Documentation for the code is also available on the [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/stackwrap4j/files/) site.

### Authors

[Bill Cruise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1288)
[Justin Nelson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2598)

### Contact

Please feel free to leave feedback here in the Answers section or on the [StackWrap4J project discussion forum](https://sourceforge.net/projects/stackwrap4j/forums/forum/1158456).

Alternatively:

Bill is available at: lizard.bill (at) gmail.com
Justin can be reached at: jjnguy13 (at) gmail.com

### Future

Currently we are focusing on adding more tests and fixing bugs.  We are also working on adding serialization so that our objects can be easily persisted, and throttling so that users of our library don't have to worry about breaking the terms of use of the API.

### Notes

The latest build was tested against version 1.0 of the API on July 28<sup>th</sup>.

Comment: Please let us know what you think of the API.  We want to know what rocks, and what sucks.

Comment: Also, any feedback on the code would be greatly appreciated.  However, we would prefer that you bash us through email rather than this public place.

Comment: Sorry guys. Wish I used Java so I could try this out :(

Comment: @George, no problem.  If you hear of anyone in need of a Java wrapper for the Stack Exchange API, send em our way.

Comment: @jjnguy: Sure will - and if someone you know needs a good PHP wrapper... please send 'em to me :)

Comment: @George, it's a deal.

Comment: I realise that this an unreasonable request, but is there any chance of hosting this on GitHub instead of/as well as SourceForge?  The fork/pull model makes it easier for external people to submit proposed contributions.

Comment: is there any way to have StackWrap4J available as a maven artifact in a known repository (one known by jarvana, as an example) ? This way, it would be really handy to use it anywhere ...

Comment: Does this work with superuser and serverfault?

Comment: @Mat: Yeah, I've tested it with all the Trilogy sites, including Meta.  It should work with any of the sites that have an active API route.

Comment: Are there any plans for the SE 2.0 API?

Comment: @Jack If I can find the time I'll update it, but I don't have any immediate plans to, so I don't know when that will be.

Comment: Ok - I'm about to graduate in May with my CS degree so maybe I'll have some time to look at it (after finals).

Comment: @BilltheLizard, is this still maintained?

Comment: @aioobe No, not as far as I know.

Comment: Are you aware of any similar project that is?

Comment: @aioobe I haven't used it myself, but [stackoverflow-java-sdk](https://github.com/sanjivsingh/stackoverflow-java-sdk) looks to be more up-to-date.

Answer (score 5):

The following is a quickly thrown together method that will return the accepted answer percentage of the user with the given ID.

**Note:** This is using some code that will be available in the next release.  Notice how it dramatically reduces complexity, and the length of code.

```
public static double getAcceptedAnswerPercentage(StackWrapper sw, int userId)
        throws JSONException, IOException, ParameterNotSetException {
    int acceptedCount = 0;
    int answerCount = 0;
    List<Answer> answers = new AnswerFromUserList(sw, (AnswerQuery) new AnswerQuery()
            .setIds(userId));
    for (Answer a : answers) {
        answerCount++;
        if (a.isIsAccepted())
            acceptedCount++;
    }
    return acceptedCount / (double) answerCount;
}
```

Are you tired of manually paging queries?  We were too.  Introducing the **`AutoFetchList`**!!

The class `AutoFetchList` will automatically pull the next pages as needed.  Looks like a list, acts like a list...must be a list.  Just throw it a Query and it will take care of the paging for you.

There is a partial implementation of this in the `datastructures` package of the latest release.  It is partially functional.  But, the code above will run and work.

Answer (score 5):

### Search Examples

#### Questions

You can search for questions with StackWrap4J by instantiating a `StackWrapper` then calling the `search` method.  Before calling `search`, you have to create a `SearchQuery`, which is a simple parameter object.

```
StackWrapper so = new StackOverflow();

SearchQuery query = new SearchQuery();
query.setTags("swing");
query.setNotTagged("java");
query.setPageSize(10);

List<Question> questions = so.search(query);
System.out.println("Questions: " + questions.size());

for(Question q : questions) {
    System.out.println("Id " + q.getPostId() + ":\t" + q.getTitle());
    System.out.println("Tags: " + q.getTags());
}
```

If you don't set the tags, nottagged, or intitle parameter in the `SearchQuery`, the `search` method will throw an exception.

If you need to modify your search, you can reuse the same query.  If I decide I want to add the `[scala]` tag to the search I did above, I could just add the tag and call `search` again.

```
query.addTag("scala");
questions = so.search(query);
...
```

#### Users

You can do a search for users with similar names using the `listUsers` method and a `UserQuery` object.  You just have to set the filter in the query.

```
UserQuery uquery = new UserQuery();
uquery.setFilter("Bill");
uquery.setPageSize(10);
List<User> bills = so.listUsers(uquery);

for(User u : bills) {
    System.out.println("Username: " + u.getDisplayName());
}
```

Comment: Question about "users": how can I get the other metadata returned in a `users` API call: like "total", "pagesize", etc? (did I just totally miss this getter in the javadoc?)

Comment: @rascher: Those will be in the `MetadataList` returned by the methods in `StackWrapper`.  It looks like we made a mistake and didn't expose that data, because those methods return `List`, which you'll have to cast.

Answer (score 4):

### Proxy Example

Sometimes you need to use a Proxy to access the internet.  At my company we need to.  StackWrap4J provides the ability to specify a Proxy server to rout connections through.

Below is a short code sample that configures the proxy, and then pulls every answer that I (2598) have given.

```
Proxy prox = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(
            "proxy.my.company.com", 80));
HttpClient.proxyServer = prox;
StackWrapper sw = new StackOverflow();
AnswerQuery query = new AnswerQuery();
query.setPageSize(PageQuery.MAX_PAGE_SIZE).setIds(2598);
List<Answer> allAnswers = new AnswerFromUserList(sw, query);
```

It is as simple as setting the public `proxyServer` property of the `HttpClient` class.  That proxy will be used continually unless you set `proxyServer` to `null`.

Answer (score 3):

### Timeout Example

If you find that a response is taking too long for your app, you can set a timeout on the request.

If a timeout occurs, a [`java.net.SocketTimeoutException`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/SocketTimeoutException.html) is thrown.  The default timeout is `0` which means infinite, so you don't have to worry about the exception if you never set a timeout.

```
StackWrapper sw = new StackOverflow();
// Set the timeout globally (1ms is way too short)
// But you will get to see the exception generated
HttpClient.setTimeout(1); // You shouldn't use 1, it will always timeout
sw.getUserById(2598);
```

So, instead of waiting for the response forever, you can time it out, and ask the user to try again later.

(This is very similar to how you would set the proxy server like in the proxy example)

Answer (score 2):

### Version Updates:

#### Version 1.0.1   [[download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/stackwrap4j/files/StackWrap4J-1.0.1.jar/download)]

- Added serialization to StackWrapper, all entities, and all queries
- Url encoded user entered `String` parameters (i.e. `" " => "%20"`)
- Set followRedirect on each connection instance instead of JVM-wide.  (This was causing problems with Google App Engine)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this, I was able to get an Android proof-of-concept working very quickly.

I wanted to build the latest version from SVN because it has some changes that aren't in the most recent binary but there doesn't appear to be a build script in the repository.  The structure seems straightforward, so I could write my own build.xml, but maybe you have something already that you use?

One minor suggestion I have is that it would be more convenient if the API docs were on the web somewhere rather, particularly for people who just want to browse to get an idea of the structure and capabilities of the library.

Comment: Thanks for your interest!  To build the project, I just put it in Eclipse.  And I know Bill uses Netbeans.  I will look into putting the documentation in a more accessible place.

Comment: @jjnguy I use IntelliJ but I just created a quick-and-dirty Ant script to build it, seemed to do the job fine.  I just wanted the badge count stuff that has been added in SVN.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any plans to support the use of your library in GWT? I'm getting some security-related errors trying to get it to work. See http://pastebin.com/SJTAHP0B

Comment: Is it GWT or Google App Engine that's throwing the exception?  I've not used either, but it looks like the security permission error is coming from GAE.  Is there somewhere that you can configure permissions?

Comment: @Catchwa, I think I found the error.  It looks like an easy fix.  Stand by for confirmation.

Comment: @Catchwa: It does look there was a fix that we could apply on our end.  Can you try [version 1.0.1](https://sourceforge.net/projects/stackwrap4j/files/StackWrap4J-1.0.1.jar/download) and let us know how that works for you?  We appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Also, check out our [change log answer](http://stackapps.com/questions/818/stackwrap4j-java-wrapper/1225#1225) to see what else is new.

Comment: Thanks guys for the prompt response! Yes, it's not GWT-related, more AppEngine related I think. Unfortunately, I've got another (different) exception trace. I won't have any time to look at it for another 24 hours, but I've put the stack trace at http://pastebin.com/DmARfX3L

Comment: @Catchwa, I think I know what is causing this...  I may have to set up an environment like this to test in now.  We would like to support the Google AppEngine.

Comment: @Catchwa I believe I fixed the error, but I have no way of testing it right now.  If you could let us know if the newest version on SourceForge is working that would be awesome.  I didn't update the version number, but I did upload a new file.  Just re-download v1.0.1.

Comment: @jjnguy We're getting there! Here's the next stack trace. http://pastebin.com/3uKfjnJ6

Comment: @Catchwa, this one has me stumped.  I will be installing the GAE tonight if I have time.  My goal is to get you up and running before the contest.  I will see if I can find the root cause of the error.

Comment: @Bill, check out the newest stack trace.

Comment: Hi i am making an android app.i read some documentation and the function and URLs to call to access data. but i dont know how to login a user in stackoverflow.please help provide some guideline how to login a user using stackauth in my app

Answer (score 0):

Can I authenticate my android app via your library?
If not, please add that if you can.