# Rep Compare - Utility for Comparing Reputation - Version 0.8

Tags: app, reputation, java

**New version!**  Includes a view of the posts similar to the Stack Exchange Reputation view.  Just click and drag to select a region of ansers.  (Note, still kind of buggy.  Doesn't seem to exactly match up with the points on the graph.  Working on it.) [Download it!](http://code.google.com/p/se-reputation-compare/downloads/list)

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image]
<sub>*click for full size*</sub>

### About

<sub>I just threw this together for fun.</sub>

Rep Compare is a little app made to show that [StackWrap4J](https://stackapps.com/questions/818/stackwrap4j-java-wrapper) actually works.  And, it is really interesting to compare reputation slopes between users.  Place Jon Skeet and anyone else on a graph and see how much he dominates.

I plan on adding some features to make this more similar to the Reputation tab in a user's profile.

### Features

The main feature is the ability to plot user reputation across all sites against any other user.  Other features include:

- Color-coded key
- Site icons to distinguish sites
- Ability to select any range of points [soon]
- Display posts that fall in selected range [soon]
- Remove users [soon]
- Pan and Zoom graph to any scale [future]

#### Usage

To run, just type the following in the console:

```
java -jar path/to/repCompare.jar
```

If you run the command from the directory the jar is located, the path to the jar is simply the name of the jar file.

#### License

[Apache 2.0](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0)

Since I used [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) and actually packaged it with the app, I figured I should use the same license.

#### Download

[Download it from Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/se-reputation-compare/downloads/list)

#### Platform

Compiled against Java 1.6 and tested on Windows 7.

#### Contact

If you need to get a hold of me, just shoot me an email.  jjnguy13 at gmail dot com.

#### Code

The SVN repository is located [on google code](http://code.google.com/p/se-reputation-compare/source/checkout)

It uses [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) to make dealing with time easiser. (duh)  And [StackWrap4J](https://stackapps.com/questions/818/stackwrap4j-java-wrapper) for the retrieving the data.

Comment: I am a complete n00b when it comes to Java. I've got the `.jar` file and I know I have the Java runtime installed. How to use? I double-click the `.jar` file but nothing happens.

Comment: @farseeker, I will update my post with that info.  Sorry i didn't include it.  (I just double-click on the jar)

Comment: @far, updated.  Have a look at the Usage section, and let me know if you still have issues.

Comment: @far, there is a chance that it was just throwing an exception and exiting...

Comment: It's very cool, but it needs a reset/clear feature. Maybe when 0.0.0.1.1 comes out. Maybe for 0.0.0.2 you could have a log scale option. (Who won?)

Comment: I like it. what IDE do you use? Is java your day job?

Comment: @Dennis, a remove user feature is planned, and Mexico won.  (The right decision IMO)

Comment: @code, I use Eclipse 3.5, with no GUI builder.  (Au Natural baby!)  My day job is mostly C#.  I learned Java in school, and it is my language of choice.

Comment: Hm, for some reason I can't get it to show me, it just keeps the progress bar up forever `:(` http://i.imgur.com/MI08hKj.png

Comment: @Doorknob this app is running off of an old version of the API, and it hasn't been updated in quite a while. If you like, you can check out the source to see if you can figure out what's wrong, but I don't think I'll be able to fix it. Sorry.

Comment: @jjnguy Ah okay. No worries!

Answer (score 3):

Great job!  Check out my graph.

[image: RepGraph]

Witness how I used to actually have more rep than Jon Skeet... then he *joined* the site and put an end to all that. :)

Comment: Haha, good work.  As soon as I add a zoom feature, you will be able to look more closely at the point where he swiftly defeated you.

Comment: @jjnguy: I'll be cutting it off before that, so I can bask in my August 2008 glory.  :)

Comment: hand drawn circle!

Answer (score 2):

Looks great! Here it is running on Ubuntu with my *lousy* rep. compared to Jon Skeet:
[image]

Comment: Glad you got it to work so quickly!

Comment: Just try harder, you will catch him some day... `:P`

Comment: I certainly have him beat here on StackApps! (Yes, he actually is here on StackApps)

Answer (score 2):

I got Jon Skeet beat :)

[image]

<sub><s>I get the following:</s></sub>

```
C:\Users\mark.henderson>java -jar c:\users\mark.henderson\AppData\Local\Temp\rep
Compare.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version n
umber in .class file
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:12
4)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:268)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
```

(I realise it's 0.0.0.1 so no hard feelings ;))

Comment: I'm gonna guess you only have 1.5 or before installed.  I will see about compiling the Jar for 1.5 instead of 1.6. (I'm pretty sure it is the version issue)

Comment: @Far, I'm gonna look into changing the version tomorrow.  Bed time.  If you install 1.6 it should work though.

Comment: @jjn - fair enough. I went to the page to test my version of Java and it crashed my browers (FireFox). I shall check back here in 24 hours :) Have a good night.

Comment: Wow, sun makes you jump through a ton of hoops to download the compiler for version 5.

Comment: Well, unfortunately Joda Time is compiler under 1.6, so i have to stick with that.  If you really wanna try it, here is a link to the latest version of java:  [Link](https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewProductDetail-Start?ProductRef=jre-6u21-oth-JPR@CDS-CDS_Developer)

Comment: Also, apparently 1.5 has hit End Of Life, so I don't feel too bad not supporting it.

Comment: Last comment: try `java -version` to test the version of java you have.  If it is 1.6 or 6.0 (or something similar) please let me know, cuz it should work.

Comment: @jjn - `java version "1.5.0_04"` - I'll get the update now

Comment: @jjn - that did the trick thanks. Maybe some other java-based software I've got will stop crashing now...

Comment: Glad you got it working.  Way to beat the Skeet.