# Chrome may not allow one-click userscript install now

Tags: discussion, google-chrome, scripts

- [Issue 128748:    [Regression] Unable to install extensions by running .crx file downloaded in Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128748)
- [Chrome can't (directly) install userscripts anymore](http://userscripts.org/topics/113176)
- [Chrome Fix: Extensions, apps, and user scripts cannot be installed from this web site](http://www.ghacks.net/2012/06/12/chrome-fix-extensions-apps-and-user-scripts-cannot-be-installed-from-this-web-site/)

Chrome Canary is only letting me install userscripts from the Chrome Web Store via the one-click route. There is a workaround (drag-drop the script to the Extension page), but it's cumbersome.

This is still in dev/Canary, so they may polish this up/entirely remove it before pushing to beta/stable. Hopefully. Still, we better keep a watch on this--it may be necessary to update the installation instructions on all script pages to include this nit.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately the news is bad all around.

[Sathya](https://stackapps.com/users/74/sathya) has updated the [tag wiki](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info) for [script](/questions/tagged/script) to include the following paragraph:

> As of May/June 2012, Chrome no longer allows for direct installations of off-store extensions. To install them, you'll have to download/save the .user.js file, open chrome://chrome/extensions/ (or Click on Wrench -> Tools -> Extensions & drag the *.user.js file to the Extensions tab. After that, you'll get the prompt to install the extension.

Originally [I thought this was a bug and reported it](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=130023&can=4&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary).

Comment: Don't feel bad for thinking it was a bug; the [main issue report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128748) on this was filed by a Chromium developer who thought it was a regression :)

Comment: One of the comments there really sums up the way I feel: "Perhaps it's time to fork Chromium." :P