# Android app for Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, android

Is there any android app for Stack Overflow available?

Which basic features must I include if I develop this app? Ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Existing applications for Android? **Simply browse the [android](/questions/tagged/android) tag here.**

As for writing an Android app yourself, I recommend the following Java library, which has been tested on the Android:

[StackWrap4J](https://stackapps.com/questions/818/stackwrap4j-java-wrapper)

Others can be found by browsing the [android](/questions/tagged/android)+[library](/questions/tagged/library) tags together, like so:

https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/library+java

Answer (score 2):

The [official Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin) was [released in early 2014](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-for-android-is-here/).

Answer (score 1):

I made this app, link overflow. To scraps the links from stack overflow questions.

[LinkOverflow -- list of links in a Stack Exchange post](https://stackapps.com/questions/2673/linkoverflow-list-of-links-in-a-stack-exchange-post)

Feedback appreciated. Thanks.