# LinkOverflow -- list of links in a Stack Exchange post

Tags: app

**About**

This site useful to find the links that will appear on the stackoverflow post. Give the question url then site will parse the all answers and extract the list and it will mark it with tag.

It will useful when post contains the lot of urls i.e. [List of free books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books))

**Code**

Site uses Stackoverflow API + JQuery + Bootstrap and deployed on google app engine.

**Platform**

It will work on all modern browser on desktop / mobile.

**Contact**

Send me your valuable feedback @ sohilvassa [at] gmail [dot] com

**WebSite**

Visit: http://link-overflow.appspot.com/

Comment: I think this could be more useful if there was an option to display the links in plain text (just a list of urls). This way the results could easily be fed to some script to do something with them. Also I'm not sure of the purpose of the "print" button -- Why would you want to print the title of the pages linked to but not the URLs? They even appear blue like hyperlinks, but of course if you're printing them you can't click them...

Comment: At that time i felt like printing is good feature as i wanted to print the list of the books with name and link. But now email the link will be good feature. I will work on this. Thanks.