# The StackWrap4J java wrapper gives nothing but `JSONException`s?

Tags: support, api, java

I'm using the StackWrap4J java wrapper for the Stack Overflow API.
But every code I try, that uses methods of this java wrapper, ends with this JSONException:

> net.sf.stackwrap4j.json.JSONException: **A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]**
>   at net.sf.stackwrap4j.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:423)
>   at net.sf.stackwrap4j.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:183)
>   at net.sf.stackwrap4j.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:310)
>   at net.sf.stackwrap4j.StackWrapper.getUserById(StackWrapper.java:716)
>   at stackoverflowmain.main(stackoverflowmain.java:26)
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at stackoverflowmain.main(stackoverflowmain.java:32)

This is the current code that resulted with  the above exception (but it's same for any method from the this wrapper that I have tried) :

```
StackOverflow stack = new StackOverflow();
User user = null;
try {
    user = stack.getUserById(4629408);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
int rep = user.getReputation();
System.out.print(rep);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The StackWrap4J library](https://stackapps.com/questions/818/stackwrap4j-java-wrapper) is very obsolete.  [Its page](https://stackapps.com/questions/818/stackwrap4j-java-wrapper) states:

> The latest build was tested against version 1.0 of the API on July
>   28th.

But API version 1 has been shut down for quite a while.  The API is currently at version 2.2.

Choose a different library. [The list is at `stackapps.com/questions/tagged/library+java`](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/library+java). Choose one that supports API version 2.0 or greater.